# ProgrammingError: The object was created in thread id 14408 and this is thread id 2776. Am unable to create an account

Tags: python, database, sqlite, streamlit

**Streamlit project: The error below pops up anytime I create an account. I don't know where am mistaking it as well. Please I need help **

**MY Main code**

```
import streamlit as st

# EDA PKG
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# UTILS
import os
import joblib
import hashlib # you can also use passlib and bcrypt

# VISUALISATION PKG
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
matplotlib.use('Agg')

# DATABASE
from manage_db_1 import *

# Password
def generate_hashes(password):
    return hashlib.sha256(str.encode(password)).hexdigest()

# Verify password
def verify_hashes(password, hashed_text):
    if generate_hashes(password) == hashed_text:
        return hashed_text
    return False

# Interface

def main():
    """Mortality Prediction App"""
    st.title("Disease Mortality Prediction App")
    
    menu = ['Home', 'Login', 'Signup']
    submenu = ['Plot','Prediction', 'Metrics']
    
    choice = st.sidebar.selectbox("Menu", menu)
    if choice == "Home":
        st.subheader("Home")
        st.write("What is Hepatitis?")
    elif choice == "Login":
        username = st.text_input("Username")
        password = st.text_input("Password", type="password")
        if st.sidebar.checkbox("Login"):
            create_usertable(username1,password1)
            hashed_pswd = generate_hashes(password)
            result = login_user(username, verify_hashes(password, hashed_pswd))
            #if password =="12345":
            if result:
                st.success("Welcome {}".format(username))
                
                activity = st.selectbox("Activity", submenu)
                if activity == "Plot":
                    st.subheader("Data Visualisation Plot")
                    
                elif activity == "Prediction":
                    st.subheader("Predictive Analytics")               
                
            else:
                st.warning("Incorrect Username/Password")
            
    elif choice == "Signup":
        new_username = st.text_input("User Name")
        new_password = st.text_input("Password", type='password')
        confirmed_password = st.text_input("Confirm Password", type='password')
        if new_password == confirmed_password:
            st.success("Password Confirmed")
        else:
            st.warning("Passwords not the same")
        if st.button("Submit"):
            create_usertable()
            hashed_new_password = generate_hashes(new_password)
            add_userdata(new_username, hashed_new_password)
            st.success("You have successfully created a new account")
            st.info("Login To Get Started")             
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Database Code**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("usersdata.db")
c = conn.cursor()


# FXN
def create_usertable():
    #c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userstable(username, password)')
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userstable(username TEXT, password TEXT)')
    
def add_userdata(username, password):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO userstable(username,password) VALUES (?,?)', (username,password))
    conn.commit()


def login_user(username, password):
    #c.execute('SELECT.*.FROM.userstable.WHERE.username.=?.AND.password.=?',(username,password))
    #data.=c.fetchall()
    #return.data
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM userstable WHERE username =? AND password =?',(username,password))
    data = c.fetchall()
    return data
    
    
def view_all_users():
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM userstable')
    data = c.fetchall()
    return data
```

ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 14408 and this is thread id 2776.

````
Traceback:
File "c:\users\eli\.conda\envs\eli\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\Eli\Documents\betes.py", line 89, in <module>
    main()
File "C:\Users\Eli\Documents\betes.py", line 82, in main
    create_usertable()
File "C:\Users\Eli\Documents\my_db.py", line 12, in create_usertable
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userstable(username TEXT, password TEXT)")```
````

Answer (score 0):

By default Python sqlite3 objects such as connections and cursors can only be used in the thread that creates them.  Evidently streamlit's `script_runner.py` is executing your database code in multiple threads.

The solution is to create the connections and cursors inside the database functions.  To reduce duplication you can call `execute` on the connection [directly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-shortcut-methods), for example:

```py
def login_user(username, password):
    with sqlite3.connect("usersdata.db") as conn:
        data = list(
            conn.execute('SELECT * FROM userstable WHERE username =? AND password =?',
                     (username,password)))
    conn.close()
    return data
```

It is possible to disable the restriction using objects in multiple threads by passing `check_same_thread=False` to the `connect` function.  However it would be unwise to do this, because of the risk of data corruption.

Comment: But please, the error is coming from the signup. And from the database, its pointed to the creation of the table. ```def create_usertable():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userstable(username TEXT, password TEXT)')```

Comment: You cannot have `conn` or `c` as global variables.  You need to create them inside _each_ of the database functions.

Comment: I created them in each of the functions but had the same error message. I will be glad if you could guide me in that regard by given example.

Comment: Ah, there was a typo in my code - it should be `conn.execute`, not `c.excecute`.

Comment: May be am not getting it right, kindly check the code and correct me.

Comment: May be am not getting it right, kindly check the code and correct me. ```import sqlite3
def create_usertable():
    with sqlite3.connect("usersdata.db") as conn:
        conn.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userstable(username TEXT, password TEXT)')
    def add_userdata(username, password):
    with sqlite3.connect("usersdata.db") as conn:
        conn.execute('INSERT INTO userstable(username,password) VALUES (?,?)', (username,password))
        conn.commit()```

Comment: ``` def login_user(username, password):
    with sqlite3.connect("usersdata.db") as conn:
        data = list(
 conn.execute('SELECT * FROM userstable WHERE username =? AND password =?',  (username,password)))
    return data 
def view_all_users():
    with sqlite3.connect("usersdata.db") as conn:
        conn.execute('SELECT * FROM userstable')
        data = conn.fetchall()
    return data``` Below is the new error message

Comment: ```OperationalError: database is locked
Traceback:
File "c:\users\elij\.conda\envs\eli\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\Eli\Documents\betes.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
File "C:\Users\Eli\Documents\betes.py", line 86, in main
    add_userdata(new_username, hashed_new_password)
File "C:\Users\Eli\Documents\ma_db.py", line 19, in add_userdata
    conn.execute('INSERT INTO userstable(username,password) VALUES (?,?)', (username,password))```

Comment: I though `with ...conn:` closed the connection, but it seems it doesn't.  Add `conn.close()` after each `with` (I've added it to the code in the answer).

Comment: Thanks but closing each function still didn't work. OperationalError: database is locked